# Nextjs: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

This is the error that I got while i was trying to run my Nextjs app:

```
./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I used pdf-js

And this is the function i used to fetch the pdf files so I can convert them to text

```
import * as pdfjs from "pdfjs-dist";

export async function getContent(src: string) {
  const doc = await pdfjs.getDocument(src).promise;
  const numPages = doc.numPages;
  const allTextContent = [];

  for (let pageNum = 1; pageNum <= numPages; pageNum++) {
    const page = await doc.getPage(pageNum);
    const pageTextContent = await page.getTextContent();

    allTextContent.push(pageTextContent);
  }

  return allTextContent;
}

export async function getItems(src: string) {
  const content = await getContent(src);
  const allItems = content.flatMap((pageContent) =>
    pageContent.items.map((textItem) => textItem.str || "")
  );
  return allItems;
}
```

Here is where I used the function I exported

```
  const onSubmit = async () => {
    if (form.formState.isValid) {
      const uploadedFiles = form.getValues("files");
      const filePromises: Promise<string[]>[] = [];

      // Extract text content from each uploaded PDF file
      uploadedFiles.forEach((file) => {
        const blob = new Blob([file], { type: file.type }); // Create a Blob object
        filePromises.push(getItems(URL.createObjectURL(blob)));
      });

      try {
        const extractedText = await Promise.all(filePromises);
        setPdfTextContent(extractedText.flat());
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error extracting PDF text:", error);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: That really isn't enough to help you, can you post the **full** stack trace from the error? Also are you trying to use a node-only package during SSR? You're not calling that in client-side code are you?

Answer (score 2):

[from here](https://fileinfo.com/extension/node)

> ### What is a NODE file?
>
> A NODE file contains an addon, which is a compiled library of
> functions used by one or more Node.js applications. It stores binary
> data compiled from a GYP file written in the C++ programming language.
> NODE files are similar to .MJS modules in that they allow web and
> application developers to organize code into smaller reusable
> components.

Looks like `canvas.node` is built to be used in node.js environment but you are using it on client side